# Need .py files to execute in the same directory with .html and .php files using mod_wsgi

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, mod-wsgi

I'm running CentOS 8.1 with Python 3.6.8, and Apache/2.4.37.

I'm new to mod_wsgi. I found this "hello world" example and got it to work:

https://www.ionos.com/community/hosting/python/use-mod-wsgi-to-run-python-as-a-web-application-on-centos-7/

The problem I'm having is that this appears to require each .py file to be added to its own .conf file to be added to conf.d, as seen in /etc/httpd/conf.d/helloworld.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /helloworld /var/www/python/helloworld.py

<Directory /var/www/python/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And to run on python (.py) scripts out of /var/www/python.

This is very inconvenient before it looks like each Python program needs to be hardcoded instead of running out of the /var/www/html directories. We have development in Python 2 where the .py files are executed in the same directory along with .html and .php files. Under CentOS 7 we just had an entry added to the httpd.conf to recognize all .py files and make sure they got executed by Python.

I see the author mentioned this was for security. Is there a way to do this still being secure, but so I don't have to gather up all the .py files on the server and make .conf files for it, as seen in this "hello world" example?

If my take on using mod_wsgi is completely wrong, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

The mod_wsgi also has [`WSGIScriptAliasMatch`](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIScriptAliasMatch.html) that could be useful in your case, e.g.

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/([^/]+).py /var/www/python/$1.py
```

If you don't require the shorter paths, you could also use [`WSGIScriptAlias`](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIScriptAlias.html) for the whole folder:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /python/ /var/www/python/
```

That would be equivalent to:

```
Alias /python/ /var/www/python/
<Location /python>
    SetHandler wsgi-script
    Options +ExecCGI
</Location>
```

This is similar to how you'd use mod_python's [Publisher Handler](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/tutorial.html#a-quick-start-with-the-publisher-handler):

```
<Directory /var/www/python> 
   AddHandler mod_python .py
   PythonHandler mod_python.publisher 
   PythonDebug On 
</Directory>
```

For more examples, please refer to [mod_wsgi Configuration Guidelines](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html)

Comment: How would I do this so any .py file located anywhere within the directories in /var/www/html would execute the .py file just as it executes any .php file no matter where it is in /var/www/html?

Comment: How about `AddHandler wsgi-script .py`? I really suggest reading the documentation.